# Master-Slave Amp clipping/saturating problems

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, voltage-clipping

Building a master-slave amp to drive a piezoelectric driver for a sonoluminescence experiment.  Having a problem with the amplification.

The rails are at +/- 45 V (sorted that problem out, thanks to all who helped).  Straightforward design from the data sheet of the OPA445 (45 V) op amp, with capacitive stabilization added in.

The chip: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa445.pdf

And the actual circuit I'm using. The buffer is necessary because the cheap frequency source will feed back if the input impedance isn't very high.  All op-amps have trimmer pots attached per the data sheet's instructions, and have been properly nulled.

[image: Circuit Schematic]

Circuit is driven around 25 kHz, don't think that is a problem for this chip and circuit - it's designed to drive piezos around those frequencies.  At low outputs, it seems to work fine.  But once the output voltage between the master and the slave goes to about 70 V peak to peak, increasing the input doesn't increase the output, it just clips at the top of the waveform.  I can take some pics of the o-scope output if that would help.  As far as I can tell, the output is symmetric to ground (until the clipping starts.)

Any help or info appreciated, will answer any questions I can, but will be on the road over the weekend.  Thanks in advance.

Martin

Comment: The master output begins to clip ?  or the slave output begins to clip ?  Or both ?   What is Load ?  The spec sheet shows about 15 mA capability.

Comment: are C2 and C4  4.7 nf ?  If so, the impedance of a 4.7nf @ 25kHz is 1354 ohms.  At 70 v peak to peak (35v peak, 25 VRMS), current in capacitors would be 0.018mA (18 mA), WITHOUT any further load. Could be a problem.

Comment: A scope shot would be a good idea, removing any ambiguity about what you mean when you say "clipping" and also showing the input waveform (assuming sine). I notice the minimum *Full Power Bandwidth* is 23kHz, so you could be running into slew rate limiting. If the wave form is looking more like a triangle wave than a sine that's a pretty sure sign. Trying at 10kHz drive for comparison would also likely provide insight.

Comment: Also, as @Marla mentions, those 4.7nF caps on the output are massive. Are those a chosen component or meant to model the load somehow? If chosen, how did you arrive at that value?

Comment: Values for 4.7 nF caps were taken from the data sheet example for capacitive coupling.  I'll test it out at 10 kHz tomorrow and see what I get.

Comment: Also remember that if the voltage is 70 V p-p, that means the master and slave are each producing 35 V p-p.